# Use gzip on Google Drive SDK to boost performance

Tags: performance, gzip, google-drive-api

I'm writing a Google Drive client in Java on the Google App Engine. The communication with Google Drive is working, and now I want to boost the performance. Google documentation specifies the use of gzip;

https://developers.google.com/drive/performance

How of where do i set these two HTTP headers (Accept-Encoding: gzip and User-Agent: my program (gzip)) in my Drive (com.google.api.services.drive.Drive) service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client library layer should do this for you, so there is nothing extra you need to do. Those performance tips are present for someone writing a client library themselves.